# Convert a Select ng-options to a Radio button ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select dropdown that is pulled from a service that I want to convert to a repeating radio button.

This is the working code as a drop down:

```
<select id="selectTitle" name="selectTitle" class="form-control" ng-model="selectTitle" ng-options="item.text for item in items track by item.value">
       <option value='' disabled selected>Select One...</option>
```

Then thought it would be a simple task of replacing with the following but sadly not. Mmmmm very strange.

```
 <label ng-repeat="item.text for item in items track by item.value">
     <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="selectTitle" /> {{text}}
```

So i have now create a Plunker for this and I'm still having issues, I've got it to show a certain level but just want Option 01, and Option 02 to display as labels.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

plnkr.co/edit/xNVVFohA6DeU9nCgi7fQ?p=preview

Comment: Why would you want to change it if it works? Where is the problem, does it mess up other stuff later?

Comment: It will not work, please refer: The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of <option> elements for the <select> element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression.

It is because he is trying to use syntax of ng-options in drop down as ng-repeat in radio button.

Comment: @LironIlayev If it works it does not mean that it fit the requirements...

Comment: I want it to display radio buttons and not a dropdown, hence the reason to change the code

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't use ng-options syntax in dropdown as ng-repeat syntax in radio button, 
try this:

```js
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-value="item.text"/>{{item.text}}
        </label>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So i have now create a Plunker for this and I', still having issues, I've got it to show a certain level but just want Option 01, and Option 02 to display as labels. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks. http://plnkr.co/edit/xNVVFohA6DeU9nCgi7fQ?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, if I am not mistaken, you would like to display it as a label, if yes, just remove this line 
<input name="optradio" type="radio" />

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-repeat` syntax is different from the `ng-options`

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="selectTitle" /> {{item.text}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a value as well, eg

```
 <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="selectTitle" value="{{item.value}}" />
```